# How does Carrying Capacity work with bonuses?

Tags: dnd-5e, stacking, encumbrance

For example: Bugbear (with Powerful Build) and a class feature similar to that (I do believe a bear totem barbarian can do that) would that give them a carrying capacity of a huge creature? Or just a large creature?

Comment: Also closely related: [Do multiple sources of counting as one size larger for carrying capacity stack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/115511/33707)

Comment: so,someone plz delete this before the downvotes start pouring in

Comment: Oh don't worry about it, duplicates are not necessarily bad and you have no downvotes yet. You can also choose to delete the question yourself if you are so inclined but there really is no need to do so. You can also see [this old blog post on it](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)